# Tensorproduct of multiple vectors in an array

Tags: python, numpy

I need to compute the tensor product of several pairs of vectors, that are stored in two arrays. I'll give you an example:

```
a=np.array([[3,5,1],[6,5,4]])
b=np.array([[8,2,3],[7,8,9]])
```

what I want to compute is:

```
np.array([tensorproduct(a[0],b[0]),tensorproduct(a[1],b[1])])
```

I couldn't find a good way to do this with numpy functions and I don't want to do it by splitting the arrays up into their individual vectors, because this takes way to long (I need this for a recursive simulation, so every bit of time I can save is gold). I hope there is a quick way to do this, can anyone help me?

Comment: what's the expected ouput for this array? have you looked into `np.matmul` or `np.kron`?

Comment: Show the splitting-up way, so it is clear what you are trying to do.  `tensorproduct` is not a clear enough description.

Answer (score 1):

If by tensorproduct you just mean a matmul/dot product, I think you want something like this:

```
z = a * b
z = np.sum(z, axis=1)
```

Edit:

Based on your comment what I think you want (can do) is use broadcasting to add dimensions so that you can do a simple multiplication.

```
z = x[:, :, None, None] * y[None, None, :, :]
```

Comment: Hi, what I mean by tensorproduct is the following: [5,8,1]*[4,0,2]=[[5*4,5*0,5*2],[8*4,8*0,8*2],[1*4,1*0,1*2]]=[[20,0,10],[32,0,16],[4,0,2]]

Comment: In that case I think you need to use broadcasting. For the example you have here you can do it like: `x1 = [5,8,1]; y1 = [4,0,2]` `z= x1[:,None] * y1[None,:]`

Answer (score 0):

If you want `(a[0]*b[0]).sum()` and `(a[1]*b[1]).sum()`,

You can use [`numpy.einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) with:

```
np.einsum('ij,ij->i', a, b)
```

Output: `array([ 37, 118])`